# How to collapse If, Else, For, Foreach, etc clauses?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, clause

I get stuck sometimes with very long clauses and I am looking for a way that allows me to collapse them, same way as I can collapse classes, methods and namespaces by default.

Is there a Visual Studio extension that does that? neither ReSharper nor JustCode does allow it.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `#region` if using `c#`

Comment: Generally that's a sign you should refactor your code into methods, if possible.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - not always you are viewing your own code or code that you can refactor

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Try this plugin (C# Outline Extension):

- [VS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d7e74d7-3d71-4ee5-9ac8-04b76e411ea8)
- [VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc07ec7e-abfa-425f-bb65-2411a260b926)
- [VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6c3c5dec-1534-4c42-81b1-cfd4615fd0e9)
- [VS2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9390e08c-d0aa-42f1-b3d2-5134aabf3b9a)
- [VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz0835.CSharpOutline2017)
- [VS2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Coutline2019.xyz0835-coutline2019)
- [VS2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz0835.CSharpOutline2022)

Comment: I installed it, then restarted VS 2013, but it didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: 2013 version: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6c3c5dec-1534-4c42-81b1-cfd4615fd0e9

Comment: VS2015 still need this extension

Comment: It's work.  I use it before but I forgoten name this extenssion. Thank's.

Comment: And there is [C# outline 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Coutline2019.xyz0835-coutline2019) for Visual Studio 2019 now.

Answer (score 45):

Visual studio IDE gives an option to outline the if, for, foreach, while, switch case etc.

Just go to `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C\C++- > View` and set `Outline Statement Blocks` to true.

In Visual Studio 2012+, the path is `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C\C++- > Formatting`.

Comment: +1 Thank you for that answer, unfortunately I checked and nothing similar is available for the C# editor, therefore I cannot accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: While it applies to a different language, this answer still needs more love.

Comment: Rename you .cs file to .cpp and you can do this.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I am using VS Express 2013. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

I use 2 Extensions:

[C# outline 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6c3c5dec-1534-4c42-81b1-cfd4615fd0e9)

and

[Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30)

Comment: Man, this is perfect. Makes me wonder how MS ignored such essential code editing functionality.

Answer (score 17):

select the code you want to collapse and then press ctrl+M,ctrl+H. to disable it, press ctrl+M,ctrl+U, you can also right click on the selection, and there "Plan Mode" ( I'm not sure my VS is french )

Comment: That is pretty cool, specially for people who are using Visual Studio Express hence they can't use plugins, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#region` for collapsing if, else, for and other similar clauses.
**Example:**

```
#region foreach
foreach(/*conditions*/) 
{
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    ..
    statement n;
}
#endregion
```

Now for collapse all use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: I don't think this a nice option, regions are there because code is hard to manage and move around, and since they don't make code look good enough I use this extension:  [I Hate #Regions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca)